# Qtabelview always inserts a row from 0, how the scroll bar remains in the same position

Tags: qt, qtableview

QTabelView insert a row from 0.

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0);
endInsertRows();
```

The scroll bar is always in the 0 position.but I want the scroll bar to always be in the middle of a row.The view automatically grows, but the scrrollbar position does not change.

If you insert from the last line, the position of the scroll bar will not change.

```
int count = tableview->count();
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), count, 0);
endInsertRows();
```

Comment: Could you post your code for `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows` as well ?

Comment: beginInsertRow();
endInsertRows() is QAbstractItemModel's api

Comment: ok so for your second example, you should replace `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), count, 0);` with `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), count, count);` and retry

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but if you are saying that you want a specific row to always be in the center of the view (if possible) then you can get the QModelIndex of the relevant row and call the following:
    `myTreeView->scrollTo( myItemModelIndex, QAbstractItemView::PositionAtCenter );`

Comment: myTreeView->scrollTo( myItemModelIndex, QAbstractItemView::PositionAtCenter ) that help me. thank you